# How to perform join operation similar to SQL join in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection in Azure DocumentDB where in I have documents clustered into 3 sets using a JSON property called **clusterName** for each document. The 3 clusters of documents are templated somewhat like these:

**{
"clusterName": "CustomerInformation",
"id": "CustInfo1001",
"custName": "XXXX"
},**

**{
"clusterName": "ZoneInformation",
"id": "ZoneInfo5005",
"zoneName": "YYYY"
},**

**{
"clusterName": "CustomerZoneAssociation",
"id": "CustZoneAss9009",
"custId": "CustInfo1001",
"zoneId": "ZoneInfo5005"
}**

As you can see the document for **CustomerZoneAssociation** links the documents of **CustomerInformation** and **ZoneInformation** with their Id s. I need help in querying out information from CustomerInformation and ZoneInformation cluster with the help of their Id s associated in the CustomerZoneAssociation cluster. The result of the query I am expecting is:

**{
"clusterName": "CustomerZoneAssociation",
"id": "CustZoneAss9009",
"custId": "CustInfo1001",
"custName": "XXXX",
"zoneId": "ZoneInfo5005",
"zoneName": "YYYY"
}**

Please suggest a solution which would take only 1 trip to DocumentDB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DocumentDB does not support inter-document JOINs... instead, the `JOIN` keyword is used to perform intra-document cross-products (to be used with nested arrays).

I would recommend one of the following approaches:

- Keep in mind that you do not have to normalize every entity as you would with a traditional RDBMS. It may be worth revisiting your data model, and de-normalize parts of your data where appropriate. Also keep in mind that, de-normalizing comes with its own trade offs (fanning out writes vs issuing follow up reads). Check out the following SO answer to read more on the [tradeoffs between normalizing vs de-normalizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456564/single-or-multiple-entities-per-collection-in-documentdb/27466029#27466029).
- Write a stored procedure to batch a sequence of operations within a single network request. Checkout the following SO answer for a [code sample on this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706515/should-i-denormalize-or-run-multiple-queries-in-documentdb/25734137#25734137).

Comment: The code sample in the second bullet point does not do a cross table join.